# Can't read barcodes contents with the new ML kit

Tags: java, android, barcode, google-mlkit

So far, updating my app to use the new ML kit for barcode scanning is a failure. I'm using the `Camera2` API and processing my images in this way :

```
imageToProcess = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, 0);

Task<List<Barcode>> result = scannerCodeBarre.process(imageToProcess)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(codesBarres -> {
                         // my code to exploit the result given by the ML
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        // my code to inform finding a barcode content failed
                    });
```

I can add I start to process a new image only when the result from the previous processed image has been obtained, but no matter if the previewed image contains a 2D or 3D barcode, the `Task` always triggers the `onFailure` function of it's `OnFailureListener`.

Can anyone tell me what I could be missing?

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader lecteurImage) {
    Image image;
    Object objetImage;

    image = lecteurImage.acquireNextImage();

    if (image != null) {
            objetImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, rotation);
            traitementImage(objetImage);
        }
        image.close();
    }
}

protected void traitementImage(Object image) {
    Task<List<Barcode>> résultat = scannerCodeBarre.process((InputImage) image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(codesBarres -> {
                AlertDialog.Builder constructeur;
                View vueBoite;
                CharBuffer cb;

                constructeur = new AlertDialog.Builder(activite);
                vueBoite = activite.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.resultat_lecture, null);
                constructeur.setView(vueBoite);
                constructeur.setTitle("Résultat de la lecture du code barre...");
                constructeur.setCancelable(false);
                constructeur.setNeutralButton(R.string.OK, (boite, i) -> {
                    boite.dismiss();
                });

                for (Barcode codeBarres : codesBarres) {
                    byte[] donnéeBrute;

                    donnéeBrute = codeBarres.getRawBytes();

                    switch (codeBarres.getFormat()) {
                        case FORMAT_CODE_128: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Code128);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_CODE_39: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Code39);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_CODE_93: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Code93);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_CODABAR: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Codabar);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_EAN_13: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.EAN13);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_EAN_8: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.EAN8);
                            break;
                        }
                       case FORMAT_ITF: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.ITF);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_UPC_A: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.UPCA);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_UPC_E: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.UPCE);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_QR_CODE: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.QRCode);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_PDF417: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.PDF417);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_AZTEC: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.AZTEC);
                            break;
                        }
                        case FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.DataMatrix);
                            break;
                        }

                        default: {
                            ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Inconnu);
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        cb = csd.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(donnéeBrute));

                        ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.MessageCodeBarre)).setText(cb);
                        constructeur.create().show();
                    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.d("Lecteur code-barres", "Traitement terminé en échec...");
            });
}
```

Version without listeners :

```
protected void traitementImage(Object image) {
    while (!result.isComplete()) {
       anytextView.setText("");
    }

    if (result.isComplete() & result.isSuccessful()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder constructeur;
        View vueBoite;
        CharBuffer cb;

        constructeur = new AlertDialog.Builder(activite);
        vueBoite = activite.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.resultat_lecture, null);
        constructeur.setView(vueBoite);
        constructeur.setTitle("Résultat de la lecture du code barre...");
        constructeur.setCancelable(false);
        constructeur.setNeutralButton(R.string.OK, (boite, i) -> {
            boite.dismiss();
        });

        for (Barcode codeBarres : codesBarres) {
            byte[] donnéeBrute;

            donnéeBrute = codeBarres.getRawBytes();

            switch (codeBarres.getFormat()) {
                case FORMAT_CODE_128: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Code128);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_CODE_39: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Code39);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_CODE_93: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Code93);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_CODABAR: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Codabar);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_EAN_13: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.EAN13);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_EAN_8: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.EAN8);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_ITF: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.ITF);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_UPC_A: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.UPCA);
                    break;
                }
                        case FORMAT_UPC_E: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.UPCE);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_QR_CODE: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.QRCode);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_PDF417: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.PDF417);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_AZTEC: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.AZTEC);
                    break;
                }
                case FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.DataMatrix);
                    break;
                }

                default: {
                    ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.TypeCodeBarre)).setText(R.string.Inconnu);
                }
            }

            try {
                cb = csd.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(donnéeBrute));

                ((TextView) vueBoite.findViewById(R.id.MessageCodeBarre)).setText(cb);
            constructeur.create().show();
            } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

else {
    Log.d("Lecteur code-barres", "Traitement terminé en échec...");
}

scannerCodeBarre.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a simple app with barcodes of format EAN-13 and QR codes. Here is the code of the BarCodeImageAnalyzer class. It works well.

```
@ExperimentalGetImage //Notice: @ExperimentalGetImage.
public class BarCodeImageAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private final BarcodeScanner scanner;

    public BarCodeImageAnalyzer() {

        scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient();

    }

    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {

        Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();

        if (mediaImage != null) {
            InputImage image =
                    InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotation);
// rotation coding in main class according to ML-Kit recommendation.
// https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android.

            scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(barcodes -> {
                        for (Barcode barcode : barcodes) {
                            codebarres.setText(barcode.getRawValue());
// codebarres is a TextView in the mainactivity layout.
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(results -> imageProxy.close());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but no better result...

Comment: I used the text recognition module of ML-Kit for which the coding of the recognizer task is identical to the barcode one. If you still need some advice could you share the codes of the calling method. The only reference I have is this app example found on github:https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/android-snippets/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/mlkit/BarcodeScanningActivity.java.

Comment: I have added the code I use. Hope it will help you find the bug!

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a version without the listeners as suggested in my original answer?

Comment: Code without listeners added.